# showdialog.dispose focus to another open application

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with showdialog when the showdialog form is being disposed. The Application focus to another program opened in taskbar. if nothing is opened then it focused to desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen when the dialog is getting disposed too early.  All of the windows are disabled by the dialog so Windows can't keep the focus on any of them and has to pick the window of another app.  Make sure you use the standard pattern with the Using keyword so the dialog object is disposed *after* it closes:

```
    Using dlg As New FooDialog
        If dlg.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
            '' Use dlg properties
            ''
        End If
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

its as simple as this:

```
form2.showdialog()
me.bringtofront()
```