# vb.net - showdialog() sends main window to background

Tags: vb.net, focus, modal-dialog

I have a modal window popup so a user of my application can edit some stuff, then they save it and close the window. When they close the popup window, my parent (main) window gets sent to the back of all other applications on my desktop, and then it immediately gets sent back to the front.

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Hi again! If I am not mistaken you replaced showdialog() with show() and the mainForm stopped going back; but then you wanted to know why the paint event of the mainForm was acting so weirdly (without providing any code or indication of what was done there). You are planning to do the same again or you will just focus on your question (understanding why showdialog() sends the mainform back)?

Comment: Please post the code you are using to show the modal window

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was led to my result by this question, although I didn't find the answer in this question, it led me to try other things which seem to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459791/showdialog-dispose-focus-to-another-open-application

Comment: I keep forgetting, that you can't use the enter key in comments. So anyway, so it appears that disposing of the child form too quickly causes the problem. So now, I use sub_form.close(); Main.focus(); sub_form.dispose(); and that seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: To answer your question Matt, I simply use the code "sub_form.showDialog()"

Comment: varocarbas, as you may recall in my other post, that when the child window gets disposed and I force the main window to stay on top, I saw the main window get repainted and it looked bad. Now, doing it this way, the child window does not close until the main window is repainted. So I don't see the garbled screen of the main window, but the child window does stay on the screen for a second, while the main window is being redrawn, so it looks a lot better, but there is a second of delay between closing and disappearing.

Answer (score 2):

In your main form:

```
   Dim frmDlg as New FormDialogToShow
   frmDlg.ShowDialog(Me)
```

The main form should not get sent to the back.  The child dialog will display on top of the parent.  Without the owner reference, the mainform can sometimes get sent to the back.  When you dont specify an owner form and that happens:

```
   Dim frmDlg as New FormDialogToShow
   frmDlg.ShowDialog()
   Me.BringToFront
```

(the answer is the same as the first time)

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, but this doesn't work for me. It didn't work last time either ;)

Answer (score 1):

Does your modal form somehow hide itself before `ShowDialog` line ends? This happened to me and was able to solve it by removing the `Hide` call from the modal form.

I think I read somewhere here in SO that this happens because Windows does not have an enabled window to send focus to in the active app so it sends focus to the next app instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to solve the problem:

```
' When closing the subform
' ------------------------
sub_form.close()
main.focus()
sub_form.dispose()
```

When doing this, my main form does not get sent to the back even when the sub form is modal window.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching desperately to find the answer to a similar problem. I found this to be particularly useful:

```
Private Sub Frm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Prompting = False

    Frm = Nothing
    FrmPrompt.Close()

    FrmPrompt.Dispose()
    FMain.Activate()
End Sub
```

Activate allowed my main form to not be sent behind anything else I had open.